# Can you please tell me what are the problems with parsing, json?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good afternoon, please tell me what the error could be, I receive a request in this form, I completely removed the link because of the '=' symbol, but I continue to receive an error, reviewing all the values ​​received, but I could not find a conflict.

I attach the script that I am using

```
function teststr (){
     var test = "leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=30986646&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0+%28%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%29+26.11.2021+18%3A00&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstatus_id%5D=33131353&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bold_status_id%5D=33131347&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bprice%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bresponsible_user_id%5D=7442937&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Blast_modified%5D=1637945719&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bmodified_user_id%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_user_id%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdate_create%5D=1637694044&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bpipeline_id%5D=1635139&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=451580&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=tilda&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=469607&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=475269&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B3%5D%5Bid%5D=480372&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D0%A3&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B4%5D%5Bid%5D=483228&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%2B2&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B5%5D%5Bid%5D=485606&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D1%81+%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BC&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B6%5D%5Bid%5D=487238&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B7%5D%5Bid%5D=490756&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B8%5D%5Bid%5D=493262&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B9%5D%5Bid%5D=493402&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Baccount_id%5D=24809335&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=683303&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=utm_referrer&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcode%5D=UTM_REFERRER&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=681646&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=681648&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=45+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD.&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bid%5D=928932&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+1+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=4204970&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bid%5D=678201&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bid%5D=913962&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=5&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=4198692&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B6%5D%5Bid%5D=673089&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=ID+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B6%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=290330-382828982&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B7%5D%5Bid%5D=673093&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B7%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=26.11.2021&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B8%5D%5Bid%5D=673091&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B8%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=18%3A00&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B9%5D%5Bid%5D=928936&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B9%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1637701200&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B10%5D%5Bid%5D=928940&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%92%D0%A3+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B10%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1637874000&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B11%5D%5Bid%5D=928942&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B11%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1637874000&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B12%5D%5Bid%5D=928944&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B12%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1637787600&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B13%5D%5Bid%5D=670612&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=REFERER&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B13%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=SSilka&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bid%5D=680880&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bname%5D=FORMNAME&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bcode%5D=FORMNAME&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B15%5D%5Bid%5D=671845&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B15%5D%5Bname%5D=UTM_SOURCE&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B15%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=blogger&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B16%5D%5Bid%5D=671847&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B16%5D%5Bname%5D=UTM_MEDIUM&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B16%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=rg&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B17%5D%5Bid%5D=671849&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B17%5D%5Bname%5D=UTM_CAMPAIGN&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B17%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=nasty__tasty&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B18%5D%5Bid%5D=670608&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B18%5D%5Bname%5D=TRANID&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B18%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2225828%3A2726134801&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B19%5D%5Bid%5D=670610&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B19%5D%5Bname%5D=FORMID&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B19%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=form319161715&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_at%5D=1637694044&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bupdated_at%5D=1637945719&account%5Bsubdomain%5D=mylogoped&account%5Bid%5D=24809335&account%5B_links%5D%5Bself%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.amocrm.ru";
       var res = form2Json(test);
    Logger.log(res);
    }
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input (строка 42, файл form2Json)

```
function form2Json(formString) {
  'use strict';
  let obj;
  let i;
  let pt;
  let keys;
  let j;
  let ev;
  if (typeof form2Json.br !== 'function') {
    form2Json.br = function(repl) {
      if (repl.indexOf(']') !== -1) {
        return repl.replace(/\](.+?)(,|$)/g, function($1, $2, $3) {
          return form2Json.br($2 + '}' + $3);
        });
      }
      return repl;
    };
  }
  formString =
    '{"' +
    (formString.indexOf('%') !== -1
      ? decodeURIComponent(formString)
      : formString) +
    '"}';
  obj = formString
    .replace(/\=/g, '":"')
    .replace(/&/g, '","')
    .replace(/\[/g, '":{"');
  obj = JSON.parse(
    obj.replace(/\](.+?)(,|$)/g, function($1, $2, $3) {
      return form2Json.br($2 + '}' + $3);
    })
  );
  pt = ('&' + formString)
    .replace(/(\[|\]|\=)/g, '"$1"')
    .replace(/\]"+/g, ']')
    .replace(/&([^\[\=]+?)(\[|\=)/g, '"&["$1]$2');
  pt = (pt + '"').replace(/^"&/, '').split('&');
  for (i = 0; i < pt.length; i++) {
    ev = obj;
    keys = pt[i].match(/(?!:(\["))([^"]+?)(?=("\]))/g);
    for (j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(ev, keys[j])) {
        if (keys.length > j + 1) {
          ev[keys[j]] = {};
        } else {
          ev[keys[j]] = pt[i].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g, '');
          break;
        }
      }
      ev = ev[keys[j]];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Декодированный полученный запрос, подскажите пожалуйста, что я пропустил ?

```
leads[update][0][id]=30986646
leads[update][0][name]=Елизавета+(Дмитрий)+26.11.2021+18:00
leads[update][0][status_id]=33131353
leads[update][0][old_status_id]=33131347
leads[update][0][price]=0
leads[update][0][responsible_user_id]=7442937
leads[update][0][last_modified]=1637945719
leads[update][0][modified_user_id]=0
leads[update][0][created_user_id]=0
leads[update][0][date_create]=1637694044
leads[update][0][pipeline_id]=1635139
leads[update][0][tags][0][id]=451580
leads[update][0][tags][0][name]=tilda
leads[update][0][tags][1][id]=469607
leads[update][0][tags][1][name]=Вводное
leads[update][0][tags][2][id]=475269
leads[update][0][tags][2][name]=Партнерка
leads[update][0][tags][3][id]=480372
leads[update][0][tags][3][name]=ВУ
leads[update][0][tags][4][id]=483228
leads[update][0][tags][4][name]=Акция++2
leads[update][0][tags][5][id]=485606
leads[update][0][tags][5][name]=Посоветоваться+с+мужем
leads[update][0][tags][6][id]=487238
leads[update][0][tags][6][name]=Мобильный
leads[update][0][tags][7][id]=490756
leads[update][0][tags][7][name]=Чтение
leads[update][0][tags][8][id]=493262
leads[update][0][tags][8][name]=неделя+в+подарок
leads[update][0][tags][9][id]=493402
leads[update][0][tags][9][name]=людаговорушкина
leads[update][0][account_id]=24809335
leads[update][0][custom_fields][0][id]=683303
leads[update][0][custom_fields][0][name]=utm_referrer
leads[update][0][custom_fields][0][code]=UTM_REFERRER
leads[update][0][custom_fields][1][id]=681646
leads[update][0][custom_fields][1][name]=Сотрудник,+Yclients
leads[update][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][value]=Лапина+Марина
leads[update][0][custom_fields][2][id]=681648
leads[update][0][custom_fields][2][name]=Длительность+процедуры,+Yclients
leads[update][0][custom_fields][2][values][0][value]=45+мин.
leads[update][0][custom_fields][3][id]=928932
leads[update][0][custom_fields][3][name]=Менеджер+1+линии
leads[update][0][custom_fields][3][values][0][value]=Кочетова+Ольга
leads[update][0][custom_fields][3][values][0][enum]=4204970
leads[update][0][custom_fields][4][id]=678201
leads[update][0][custom_fields][4][name]=Регион
leads[update][0][custom_fields][4][values][0][value]=Краснодарский+край
leads[update][0][custom_fields][5][id]=913962
leads[update][0][custom_fields][5][name]=Возраст+ребенка
leads[update][0][custom_fields][5][values][0][value]=5
leads[update][0][custom_fields][5][values][0][enum]=4198692
leads[update][0][custom_fields][6][id]=673089
leads[update][0][custom_fields][6][name]=ID+записи,+Yclients
leads[update][0][custom_fields][6][values][0][value]=290330-382828982
leads[update][0][custom_fields][7][id]=673093
leads[update][0][custom_fields][7][name]=Дата+записи,+Yclients
leads[update][0][custom_fields][7][values][0][value]=26.11.2021
leads[update][0][custom_fields][8][id]=673091
leads[update][0][custom_fields][8][name]=Время+записи,+Yclients
leads[update][0][custom_fields][8][values][0][value]=18:00
leads[update][0][custom_fields][9][id]=928936
leads[update][0][custom_fields][9][name]=Требует+дозвона+(Т)
leads[update][0][custom_fields][9][values][0]=1637701200
leads[update][0][custom_fields][10][id]=928940
leads[update][0][custom_fields][10][name]=Подтвердили+ВУ+(Т)
leads[update][0][custom_fields][10][values][0]=1637874000
leads[update][0][custom_fields][11][id]=928942
leads[update][0][custom_fields][11][name]=Занятие+прошло+(Т)
leads[update][0][custom_fields][11][values][0]=1637874000
leads[update][0][custom_fields][12][id]=928944
leads[update][0][custom_fields][12][name]=Записан+на+пробное+(Т)
leads[update][0][custom_fields][12][values][0]=1637787600
leads[update][0][custom_fields][13][id]=670612
leads[update][0][custom_fields][13][name]=REFERER
leads[update][0][custom_fields][13][values][0][value]=SSilka
leads[update][0][custom_fields][14][id]=680880
leads[update][0][custom_fields][14][name]=FORMNAME
leads[update][0][custom_fields][14][values][0][value]=форма
leads[update][0][custom_fields][14][code]=FORMNAME
leads[update][0][custom_fields][15][id]=671845
leads[update][0][custom_fields][15][name]=UTM_SOURCE
leads[update][0][custom_fields][15][values][0][value]=blogger
leads[update][0][custom_fields][16][id]=671847
leads[update][0][custom_fields][16][name]=UTM_MEDIUM
leads[update][0][custom_fields][16][values][0][value]=rg
leads[update][0][custom_fields][17][id]=671849
leads[update][0][custom_fields][17][name]=UTM_CAMPAIGN
leads[update][0][custom_fields][17][values][0][value]=nasty__tasty
leads[update][0][custom_fields][18][id]=670608
leads[update][0][custom_fields][18][name]=TRANID
leads[update][0][custom_fields][18][values][0][value]=2225828:2726134801
leads[update][0][custom_fields][19][id]=670610
leads[update][0][custom_fields][19][name]=FORMID
leads[update][0][custom_fields][19][values][0][value]=form319161715
leads[update][0][created_at]=1637694044
leads[update][0][updated_at]=1637945719
account[subdomain]=mylogoped
account[id]=24809335
account[_links][self]=https://mylogoped.amocrm.ru
```

Comment: I just tried the code and it gives me JSON some keys of which don't look well. For example: `"name": "Сотрудник}}}}},+Yclients"`, etc. I see the several `}` between the double quotes. Looks like a parsing error, but It's way above my paygrade to untangle and fix the parsing algorithm, sorry.

Comment: My guess, the parser doesn't handle a comma `,` inside values

Comment: Yes, it's the commas `%2C`. It works fine as soon as I replace all commas with underlines in the input string:  `test = test.replace(/%2C/g,'_')`

Comment: Try using this in the future: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have not tried it yet, I am very busy with work, as soon as I test it, I will unsubscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is the 99% working solution.

Replace the line (22):

```
? decodeURIComponent(formString)
```

with

```
? decodeURI(formString)
```

And change the line:

```
ev[keys[j]] = pt[i].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g, '');
```

with

```
ev[keys[j]] = decodeURIComponent(pt[i].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g, ''));
```

It will get you correct JSON.

But I didn't manage to get the decoded value for URL. It still looks like `"self":"https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.amocrm.ru"`. Which is not a big deal I suppose.